# Why AppEventsLogger.logEvent is undefined?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

- react-native: 0.40
- react-native-fbsdk: 0.5

I want to use react-native-fbsdk in my React Native project to log events and I did all by instruction for this library. But when I tried to launch it on iOS emulator I got an error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'AppEventsLogger.logEvent')

Answer (score 1):

This seems issue in react-native-fbsdk. refer following link

[AppEventsLogger.logEvent](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/issues/106)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `react-native link react-native-fbsdk` worked. Also run `react-native run-android` after linking.

Hope this helps.